# How can I broadcast an object in Angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How can I broadcast an object through an event?

Currently I am trying:

```
app.run ($rootScope) ->
    message = {type: 'channel', action: 'create', data: { name: "ssss", id: 0}}
    $rootScope.$broadcast('message', message)

angular.module('WebChat').controller 'ChannelController', ($scope) -> 
    $scope.$on 'message', (message) ->
        console.log message
        console.log 'hi'
```

But I am getting no output

**Edit**
I got it working. It seems that the first parameter of the callback function is the scope. I had to change the controller to:

```
angular.module('WebChat').controller 'ChannelController', ($scope) -> 
    $scope.$on 'message', (scope, message) ->
        console.log message
        console.log 'hi'
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are getting no output in your case since you are **broadcasting before a controller is ready to accept messages**. The module's run method is executed very early in the application's life-cycle, before controller's scopes are ready to listen to messages.

Here is the jsFiddle that illustrates this, check the console to see that broadcast happens before a listener is ready: http://jsfiddle.net/vPq2P/3/

Comment: I have a similar situation, where I need to [load YouTube IFrame API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference#Getting_Started). I've tried putting the load code inside run() as well as outside trying to load it last, but no matter where I put it the broadcast always happens before my controller is ready to listen, unless I do a timeout of 1000 or more (1500 seems to work best). Is there a way to guarantee proper order listen->broadcast without using timeouts? I know my question may seem vaguely broad, but I can provide more details if need be. Thanks.